# When mounting dir to RAM, will contents remain after computer reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, mount, tmpfs

I mounted a cache directory to tmpfs for faster performance on my website using this command:

```
tmpfs on /var/cache type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=102400k,mode=777)
```

It seems to be working well, however, I noticed that after rebooting my machine (with `poweroff`), the files that were in the cache remained.

Overall this is ok with me, but I want to make sure my mount to the RAM is working; I might be misunderstanding something, or maybe I set it up incorrectly.

So - doesn't the RAM get wiped on reboot? If so, why were the files still there? Does that mean my /var/cache directory is really on disk and not in memory? Is there a way to verify where the files are saved?

Thanks!

Comment: `/var/cache` directory exists on the disk, probably with some content. After mounting an empty filesystem over it, you don't see the content from the disk there (but in general programs still may). After rebooting you do, unless you "overmount" something else *again*. Did you mount again after rebooting? (manually or via `fstab` or in any way). [RAM may not lose data immediately](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack#Technical_details) but no part of the OS should reuse random "old" data in RAM or swap. I'm sure the files that remained have nothing to do with RAM not being wiped.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your response. The files that were there after reboot were files that were written by me while /var/cache was mountedt to tmpfs. Yes, I remount by adding tmpfs /var/cache/fastcache tmpfs size=100M,mode=0777 0 0 to /etc/fstab

Comment: The line in `fstab` specifies `/var/cache/fastcache` which is not `/var/cache`, so I doubt it's relevant, unless you're talking about files in `fastcache` from the beginning. I don't know exactly what's going on because your description is more hand waving than hard data, but I know Linux does not reuse random "old" data in RAM. If it did, it would generate garbage after each poweroff. Also note programs may recreate their cache *structure* quite fast. Are you sure the actual file was from the past, not recreated? Cache is usually something you can calculate or retrieve from elsewhere.

Comment: Are you sure that files that you modified were stored back into `/var/cache`, or were the original contents reloaded after the boot?

Comment: The correct directory is `/var/cache/fastcache` in both places.

Comment: The cache writes files to /var/cache/fastcache. Up until yesterday, /var/cache/fastcache was a regular dir, and then I mounted it to tmpfs. Between loading it to tmpfs, and reboot, a certain file X was written to /var/cache/fastcache. After reboot, that file was still there. Please let me know if this is helpful or if you need more specific data.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and gather all the relevant data there. We ask for additional information in comments but most of your replies should be edited into the question. The point is users shouldn't read all the comments to get the whole picture, the question should be self-contained. A good practice is to edit the question and then only notify (in comments) the user who requested the information (e.g. "@Kamil Please see new details in the question body").